# Trying to set up bash command

Tags: path, symlink, bash

I was trying to set up a bash command in Terminal on a Mac.

The scripts run correctly when I execute them directly.

I set up symlinks in /usr/local/bin/ to the current location of the scripts. When I try to run it off the symlink, it doesn't work. I don't believe the issue is the $PATH, because pip, git, ipython all exist in this location. When I edit the $PATH setting, these fail.

Suggestions?

Comment: try `ls -l` against the symlinks to see if they are set correctly.

Comment: And check '`ls -lL`' - without the capital L, you will see where the link points, but not necessarily that there is nothing at the far end of the link.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`ls -l /usr/local/bin/foo` and see where your symlink is *actually* pointing.  Betcha it's broken.

If not, try running `/usr/local/bin/foo`.  If that works, it was your PATH that's wrong, despite what you said in the OP.

The only other thing that would cause this behavior is if the script is reading `$0` (its own name as executed).  With a symlink, that will have a different value.

Answer (score 0):

I found my own answer... The symlinks were created by an automated file which was gabbing my pwd. I was also using virtualenv, so to get it to work, I had to activate the virtualenv and be inside the folder that had the script that created the symlinks.

Comment: I respectfully submit that symbolic links in /usr/local/bin should probably not be dependent on whether or not you are in a particular virtual environment.

Answer (score 0):

I install my commands in `$HOME/bin` instead of `/usr/local/bin`, but it does not matter much.  As hinted in the comments, one question is whether the symlinks are set correctly.

- Check which command the shell thinks you should execute: `which command`
- Check that the link in `/usr/local/bin` points to the correct file (and has execute permission, etc):

  - `ls -l /usr/local/bin/command`
  - `ls -lL /usr/local/bin/command`
- Check that the interpreter path in the shebang is correct:

  - `file /usr/local/bin/command`
- Check that `/usr/local/bin` is actually on your PATH: `echo $PATH`

If none of that shows up a problem, show us the results of the commands above.